# Android CountDownTimer not working

Tags: android, intentservice, countdowntimer

I am writing a service intent which scans the network for a UDP broadcast from another device on the network.  When the device is found it sends a message back to the main activity and then it does its thing.  The problem is I need to set a timeout of some sort for this scan so if it does not find a device after a certain amount of time I can tell the main activity that.  My first thought was to use a countdown timer but it isnt working.  Here is the code for the method that scans for broadcast

```
public void getIP()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000){

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Timer Finished");

            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        }.start();
        try {
            UDPSocket = new DatagramSocket(55555, InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"));
            UDPSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            byte[] buf = new byte[512];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            while(shouldContinue){
                try {
                    UDPSocket.receive(packet);
                    InetAddress senderAddress = packet.getAddress();
                    String Sender = senderAddress.getHostAddress();

                    UDPSocket.close();
                    shouldContinue = false;

                    pingIP(Sender);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            sendIPBack("device not found local");

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

sendIPBack is just a method that returns a message to the main activity.  Any idea why the onFinish and onTick methods never execute?

Thanks

Comment: I ran the same countdowntimer code on my main activity and triggered it with a button.  onTick and onFinish work great there.  Just will not work inside my IntentService.  Weird.  Any ideas?  Can you not use a countdowntimer in an IntentService Class?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out the issue here.  It wasnt actually a problem with the countdown timer not starting, it was that it was running in the same thread of my UDP listener which was locking up the thread.  You can absolutely run a countdown timer in a service or intentservice.  Hope this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this comes down to how an IntentService works. Basically when you start an IntentService it creates a worker thread which does whatever work it needs to do and then it will self-terminate.

In your code as soon as doWakefulWork exits then the IntentService will terminate. As a result your CountDownTimer will be terminated along with the IntentService.

If you want to do this kind of thing you should be using a regular Service and not an IntentService.